# How to split a string after specific character in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I am working in SQL Server studio manager 2014

I found this and it is sort of close to what I am wanting, but not quite perfect.

```
Col2 = RIGHT([HospCode],LEN([HospCode])-CHARINDEX('.',[HospCode]))
```

My data looks like this

ABC.FRED.123
ABC.STEVE
ABC.SUSAN
ABC.TED.4456
ABC.WILL
ABC.TABITHA.11
ABC.TODD

I want to get rid of the "ABC." and the ".xxx" number section IF it exists and only see the Name section. So I want my final output to be something like:

FRED
STEVE
SUSAN
TED
WILL
TABITHA
TODD

Can anyone assist? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to use **ParseName()** with a **Reverse()** (or two)

Since Name will always be the second of two or three, we reverse the string, apply ParseName(...,2), and Reverse the result back.

```
Declare @YourTable table (HospCode varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('ABC.FRED.123'),
('ABC.STEVE'),
('ABC.SUSAN'),
('ABC.TED.4456'),
('ABC.WILL'),
('ABC.TABITHA.11'),
('ABC.TODD')

Select A.*
      ,Reverse(ParseName(Reverse(HospCode),2))
 From @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
HospCode        (No column name)
ABC.FRED.123    FRED
ABC.STEVE       STEVE
ABC.SUSAN       SUSAN
ABC.TED.4456    TED
ABC.WILL        WILL
ABC.TABITHA.11  TABITHA
ABC.TODD        TODD
```

Comment: John,

You rock my man!!!  NI have spent 4 hours messing with this today!  I have no idea whats happening here so I will read up on the Parse function. 

Seriously THANK YOU

Comment: @DoNotLikeIT Happy it helped.   I'll add some more context